# What does serial.begin() do?

Tags: arduino

I'm confused about the purpose of `serial.begin()`. For instance:

```
serial.begin(baud)
```

Where 'baud' refers to baud rate.

What is the purpose of this function?

Comment: Yes,'baud' refers to baud rate. [Arduino website for begin() description](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin)

Comment: Have you [read the manual](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin)? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search:

> Sets the data rate in bits per second (baud) for serial data
>   transmission. For communicating with the computer, use one of these
>   rates: 300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 38400,
>   57600, or 115200. You can, however, specify other rates - for example,
>   to communicate over pins 0 and 1 with a component that requires a
>   particular baud rate.

Link : http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin

Basically it sets up the USART with a specific transfer rate, e. g. 1200 bits per second.